# gnuplot pm3d scatter plot - How to remove data points and interpolate

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, point, interpolation

I have data representing an electric field spread evenly over a 2d lattice. I am looking to have a 3d plot of the results, generated using 'set pm3d' but without the data points themselves being plotted, and possibly to interpolate between the lattice points. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `set pm3d interpolate 2,2; splot 'test.dat' with pm3d`?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! It was the 'with pm3d' bit that I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get interpolation between the grid points, use the `interpolate` option:

```
set pm3d interpolate 2,2
splot 'test.dat' with pm3d
```

Comment: 2nd time you made my day today @Christoph .

tyvm